# Copy to clipboard in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I know there is a way to copy to clipboard by clicking a button on website with js. But I would like to know if this could be working with Discord.js. For example, on event `interactionCreate`, clicking a button more specifically. And then I will have the String I that wanted in my clipboard. Does Discord allows us to interact with the devices clipboard? Lmk if you have clues on it.

### Why do I need this?

Because I would like to get a message template each time I used a slash command. And then it will generated a embed message as output. On computer client I can simply highlight and copy it, but it just can't let me copy it in the mobile devices. Therefore, I want to have a simple method to copy the contents from Discord Embed Message easily.

Comment: No, this isn't possible. But there might be an alternative solution if you include more info about what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @CryptoAlgorithm i have made some updated on why i need this. If it is not possible, would it be a good choice on sending a text document instead of embed message, or make it on the web and allowing me to copy it to clipboard with the web browser js method?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at how bots like MEE6 do it, they add a link for mobile devices to easily copy the message content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discord.js (and all other Discord libraries) only allow you to interact with Discord's API and not the user's client directly, **it is not possible to manipulate the user's clipboard through Discord bots**, but there are some alternatives that let you achieve something similar:

- **Sending the text in a separate message:**
  You can send the text you want your users to be able to copy in the body of a separate messaage, either directly or inside a code block, if your text contains formatting that you don't want to lose when sending.
- **Uploading the text to a paste service:**
  You can programatically upload the text you want your users to be able to copy to some paste service like Pastebin, Hastebin or Gist. Hastebin, for example, [allows you to create pastes by `POST`ing to an endpoint](https://github.com/toptal/haste-server/wiki/POST-api).